# What is correct way of sending list/tabular data JSON with REST?

Tags: json, api, rest, format

I am working on a RESTful APIs. One of our screen shows table with Grand total.

Below are two JSON responses for returning data

First

```
    [
            {
                    "name": "Richard",
                    "bank_balance": 3000,
                    "assets_worth": 4000,
                    "total": 7000
            },
            {
                    "name": "John",
                    "bank_balance": 1000,
                    "assets_worth": 2000,
                    "total": 3000
            },
            {
                    "name": "Total",
                    "bank_balance":4000,
                    "assets_worth": 6000,
                    "total": 10000
            }    
    ]
```

Second

```
    {
            "rows": [
                    {
                            "name": "Richard",
                            "bank_balance": 3000,
                            "assets_worth": 4000,
                            "total": 7000
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "John",
                            "bank_balance": 1000,
                            "assets_worth": 2000,
                            "total": 3000
                    }
            ],


            "grand_total": 
            {
                    "name": "Total",
                    "bank_balance":4000,
                    "assets_worth": 6000,
                    "total": 10000
            }    
    }
```

Which one is more correct considering REST standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST is merely an architecture style for designing networked applications. It doesn't directly answer to your question on data structuring.

Personally I would go with the first approach (just without the total row) as grand total can be trivially calculated from the row data, resulting in something like:

```
[
  {
    name: "Richard",
    bank_balance: 3000,
    assets_worth: 4000,
    total: 7000
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    bank_balance: 1000,
    assets_worth: 2000,
    total: 3000
  }
]
```

I think the important design principle here is that your API should not be opinionated about data representation. Some applications that use your API may choose to display data in tabular format, while other applications may choose some other representations. A good API is able to cater equally well different applications (and use cases).